# Can you apply a CSS filter to background-image of a div style element?

Tags: css, background-image, css-filters

Here is the code that I'm looking at:

> ```
>  <div class="fullwidth-box vas_row-back1" style="background-color:
>  rgba(99,59,0,0.79);background-image:
>  url(&quot;http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/myphoto.jpg&quot;);background-position:
>  center center;background-repeat:
>  no-repeat;padding-top:80px;padding-right:40px;padding-bottom:80px;padding-left:40px;margin-bottom:
>  60px;margin-top:
>  30px;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-
>  background-size:cover;background-size:cover;background-
>  attachment:none;">
> ```

I can control the CSS for the .vas_row-back1 class, but I cannot change the output of the style= of the div because the theme creates that.

What I want to do is apply a filter to the image background. When I use:

```
.vas_row-back1[style] {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(80%); /* Safari */
filter: grayscale(80%); }
```

The filter applies to the *entire* div, including contents.

When I try:

```
.vas_row-back1[style]:background-image {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(80%); /* Safari */
filter: grayscale(80%); }
```

It doesn't register at all, breaks the class. I want to be able to have the filter apply only to the background image of the DIV but not the contents. Do you think this is possible? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
background-blend-mode: difference;
```

If it fits your browser requirements: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a separate div with the background image nested inside this main div.

Another alternative is using a pseudo element (`:before` / `:after`) with the background style.